# Incorrect use of Scaled causes crash

Tags: graphics, bugs, crash

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

While playing with `Scaled`, I made a syntax error which caused a crash instead of an error message ...

Do you get the same ? (I have v.10.0.2, OS X 10.9.5.)

This is how I can reproduce that :

Let's define a graphic primitive (no crash here) :

```
p = Disk[{0., 0.}, Scaled[{0.2, 0.2}, 2.]]
```

(the syntax error is the second parameter of `Scaled`)

To crash, try to display the corresponding graphic :

```
Graphics@p
```

It "works" also with `Circle` instead of `Disk`, and maybe with others ?

Comment: Confirmed in 10.0.2 under Windows 7.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Windows 8.1 using Mathematica 8, 9, and 10. A syntax error should not lead to a crash. Please report this to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Well that's interesting. I'll write it up in the morning.

Comment: @Sjoerd This does not crash *Mathematica* 7 so I guess I can mark this as introduced in 8.0.

Comment: +1 for finding yet another way to induce instantaneous death LOL.

Comment: Can anyone confirm the fix for Windows, Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that this does not remain unanswered, this was fixed for 10.1. So, now it returns an FE error, as expected:

[image]

Fix is confirmed on Mac OS, Windows, and Linux.